# Need help to fix my list conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, user-input

i want it to go through the conditions but it tends to get them wrong and i cant figure out how to fix it. it goes through some of them and then makes two of them pop up as if they are right when they are actually wrong

```
OUTCOME = ['Player wins', 'Banker wins', 'Tie']
bet_choices = input("Place your bet, Banker or Player, also you can bet the tie: ").title()

if 'Player wins' in OUTCOME and bet_choices == 'Player':
    bet_money = bet_amount * 2 + bet_money

    print("You won,Your total is now " + str(bet_money))
elif 'Player wins' in OUTCOME and bet_choices == 'Banker':
    print("You bet Banker,and you lost so your total is " + str(bet_money))

elif 'Banker wins' in OUTCOME and bet_choices == 'Banker':
    bet_money = bet_amount * 2 + bet_money
    print("You won,Your total is now " + str(bet_money))

elif 'Banker wins' in OUTCOME and bet_choices == 'Player':
    print("You bet Banker,and you lost so your total is " + str(bet_money))

elif 'Tie' in OUTCOME and ate_to_1 == 'Yes':
    bet_money += tie_amount * 8
    print("Your total is now after betting on the tie " + str(bet_money))
```

i wanted to match up the users bet with the results of the game and if they get the right guess then they win money and if they dont then they lose money. Its suppose to go through all the conditions and its not

the 'player_hand' and 'Banker_hand is randomized

i want this:

```
bet = 50
userbet = Player
player_hand = 4 5 = 9
banker_hand = 4 4 = 8

player won and You won 100
```

Comment: What are the values of `OUTCOME` and `bet_choices`? What are you expecting to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: The desired output you show doesn't seem related to this code.

Comment: We can't tell you what went wrong with your code if you don't provide all of it. Show us how you are using it so we at least can reproduce whatever issue you're having but not explaining concretely.

Comment: I added the OUTCOME and the bet_choices to the code, but I expect the code to recognize which if statements is right is then print the one that matches the conditions

Answer (score 0):

Your OUTCOME is a List.
It has **Not been altered** anywhere in the provided code, hence constant.

Therefore, **All Your first sections of IF statements will ALWAYS return TRUE.**
i.e
since 'Player wins', 'Banker wins', 'Tie' are all in OUTCOME.

In essence, **only the Second part of Your IF statements Decides the Flow.**
i.e

```
and bet_choices == 'Player':  
and bet_choices == 'Banker':  
and bet_choices == 'Banker':  
and bet_choices == 'Player':  
and ate_to_1 == 'Yes':
```

Hence the First and the Fourth condition are literally the same/duplicate. (Player)
Just as the Second and the Third. (Banker)

EXAMPLE:
Assuming you are using **'Banker wins'** and `bet_choices == 'Player'`,
the code will check the first IF statement
i.e
`if 'Player wins' in OUTCOME`. This will evaluate to TRUE.
Then it will check the **and** Part of that first statement;
i.e
`and bet_choices == 'Player':`, this too will evaluate to TRUE.
Thus the code in the First statement will be executed.
The 3rd and 4th statements will NEVER be Used in Your Case.
Only Your 1st, 2nd and last statements make decisions in Your code.